# How can I use Convert.ToSingle so it can give me a decimal number?

Tags: c#, .net, math.round

[My executable][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt4AK.png

So, I'm creating an executable program that will give me my GPA based on two grades (exam 1 + exam 2). My code is running with Convert.ToSingle but the grades are not showing up as decimals, and I'm always getting numbers like 8,575 or 9,765. Is there a way that I can round up these numbers? (ex: 8,6 or 9,8).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Calcular
{
    float soma, media, valor;
    int peso = 7;
    soma = 0;

        foreach(Control controle in this.Controls)
    {
        if(controle is TextBox)
        {
            valor = Convert.ToSingle(((TextBox)controle).Text);
           
            soma += valor*peso;
            peso = 3;
            
        }
        

        media = soma / 10;
        this.Controls["label5"].Text = media.ToString();


    }
}
```

Also, I tried to solve my problem using Math.Round but I'm starting to code and perhaps I'm not using it right. But when I try to use it, I can't run my code. It shows error CS0149 - Method Name Expected.

That's how I've tried to run it (with Math.Round):

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Calcular
  {
      float soma, media, valor;
      int peso = 7;
      soma = 0;

          foreach(Control controle in this.Controls)
      {
          if(controle is TextBox)
          {
              valor = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(((media)controle).Text), 1);
             
              soma += valor*peso;
              peso = 3;
              
          }
          

          media = soma / 10;
          this.Controls["label5"].Text = media.ToString();


      }
  }
```

Is there a way that I can have decimals using Convert.ToSingle?

Thank you!

Comment: "The error: CS0149." I'm sure there's more to it than that - please include the *detailed* error message.

Comment: (It's also unclear to me how you can be getting unexpected results if you can't even run the code due to a compilation error...)

Comment: CS0149: Method Name Expected.

Comment: Okay, so you then need to show us where that's happening...

Comment: Ah, I see, you've got different code in the image, and that's where the error comes from. Please post the broken code as *text* rather than animage.

Comment: (You should *also* tell us what the input values are, so we can understand the output you're getting...)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this so I'm not sure of how to proceed. It's my first post.

Comment: Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints thoroughly, and edit your question to be clear.

Comment: You've now provided a *third* piece of code (this isn't the code that was in the image). What *exactly* do you mean by "Is there any way that I can have decimals using Convert.ToSingle"? What do you mean by "have decimals"?